# Obtaining minimum maximum output of a macro (function)

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to find to find extreme values produced by a macro as a function of input parameters:

For example purposes here is some data:

```
data Input_data;
    input X Y;
    cards;
    10 15
    20 18
    30 27
    33 41
    ;
run;
```

The following is not the actual formula (as the minimum for this is easily found analytically.) and I want computational method.
For examples sake I have semi-empirical rule, which takes three parameters in:

```
%macro Function(const1, const2 const3);
    data output;
        set input;
        X_eff1=((X > &const1.)*(X - &const1.)**2);
        X_eff2=((X > &const2.)*(X - &const2.)**2);
        X_eff3=((X > &const3.)*(X - &const3.)**2);
        Residual= Y - (1.3*X_eff1 - 2.7*X_eff2+ 3.1*X_eff3);
    run;
%mend;
```

**I want the find const1, const2 const3 which produce the minimum value for variable 'Residual'.** Can SAS do this? 
Few options that are to be considered:

a) Find global minimum

b) Find local minimum within boundary conditions, for example: `const1[0,1]` `const2[10,17]`, `const3[20, 22]`

I could generate huge table and brute force feed it to the function. However, this is not feasible if the number of input parameter rise.

I could scratch program something?

I could do this in numpy (fmin from cipy.optimize comes to mind)or R if it proves hard for SAS.

Any thoughts on how to solve it??

Comment: Minimum of the sum of the residuals? Minimum of the sum of the squared residuals? Is the real problem/formula a spline regression type thing or something else?  Knowing more about the real problem will help people suggest PROC solutions rather than DATA step.

Comment: Well, lets say that I want to minimize the sum ( residual^2). I'll check documentation about proc solutions. Thx.

Comment: Would look into PROC OR ( if you have it?) and perhaps IML. If you don't have luck here would post at communities.sas.com. There are plenty of sas/stat folks there who will help (including developers).