# Find parameter that solves the average of an exponential function in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to estimate the following equation in SAS. Unfortunately I do not have access to SAS/OR

I have 5 accounts and I would like to find the delta that solves the following:

```
(∑[1/(1+ e^(-(delta+S×(Rate) ) )] )/n  =Target
```

The parameters `S`, Target and the Rate for each account are saved in data table in SAS. As shown below

```
Ac     Rate           S     Target
 1     -5.9    1.059086       0.25
 2     -6.9    1.059086       0.25
 3     -8.1    1.059086       0.25
 4     -6      1.218584       0.25  
 5     -5.1    1.218584       0.25
```

I run this example in Solver in excel and I got a delta of 5.850219

I have 2 groups, so I would like to repeat this calculation by group

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42804051/obtaining-minimum-maximum-output-of-a-macro-function Posted the question SAS forums, which said; https://communities.sas.com/t5/Mathematical-Optimization/Obtaining-minimum-maximum-output-of-a-macro-function/m-p/350838

Comment: Do you have SAS/ETS? If so, you can still make this work.

Comment: SAS Academics on Demand offers the OR module. Assuming this is used only for learning purposes you can sign up for the free account under the Independent Learner option and access it online for free as long as you have internet.

Comment: Hi Stu, can you please provide a bit more guidance on how we can do this in SAS/ETS? I tried proc model from SAS/ETS but I can not do a do loop to calculate the sum of all the observations to calculate the average. A dummy code or further guidance will be much appreciated